# 3ds max path deform modifier won't align correctly

Tags: 3ds-max, modeling

When I try to use the "PathDeform(WSM)" modifier sometimes it works fine but other times it won't align correctly when I use the "move to path" button and just snaps to some other place.

I have tried resetting the X-form, moving pivots and rotating stuff and nothing seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found a workaround, the "move to path" button actually from what i can tell moves it to the fist vertex of the spline when it was created or something like this, so if you have heavily edited a spline you wish to use as a path and it's not moving to it correctly you can create a new one and place the starting vertex on it's pivot and than attach the original spline you wanted to use move it's vertices accordingly and delete the old segment on it. This seems to work, hope this helps other that had this problem.

Edit: also resetting X-form also helps because if you move the pivot the position of the first vertex changes because it's relative to it. I know this is not very specific and i haven't taken the time to fully understand why it works but it did help me get the result i needed.

Edit: The is an option on splines to make a vertex be the "fist vertex"
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-B8BE4AF1-466E-4EC2-B4CC-2DAFB9AE1CCB-htm.html

Answer (score 0):

It happened because while editing the "line" or "editable spline" we adjusted the pivot.
Solution:

1. select the "line" or "editable spline"
2. go to "hierarchy tab"
3. Click " reset pivot"
4. Go back to the object with PathDeform (WSM)
5. Click "Move to path" one more time